# Sending json in POST request to web api written in web.go framework

Tags: go

Im using web.go (http://webgo.io/) for writing a simple web app that accepts json in a POST request and after parsing it returns the result. Im having trouble reading the json from ctx.Params object.
Below is the code i have so far

```
package main

import  (
    "github.com/hoisie/web";
     "encoding/json"
)

func parse(ctx *web.Context, val string) string { 

    for k,v := range ctx.Params {
        println(k, v)       
    }

   //Testing json parsing
   mapB := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
   mapD, _ := json.Marshal(mapB)
   return string(mapD)

}   

func main() {
    web.Post("/(.*)", parse)
    web.Run("0.0.0.0:9999")
}
```

Though the post request gets registered i dont see anything printed on the command line for the json i posted. How can i fix this ?

Thank You

Comment: You should use `fmt.Printf` to print the values of your context (`println` is a special built-in). As for printing your JSON: returning `string(mapD)` won't print it to the command line. It'll write it to the HTTP response. You should visit `0.0.0.0:9999/`" in your browser instead.

Comment: `decoder := json.NewDecoder(ctx.Request.Body);`


`mp := make(map[string]string);`

`decoder.Decode(mp)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting any JSON data from the body of the POST request is because `hoisie/web` reads form data into `.Params`, as seen [here](https://github.com/hoisie/web/blob/5a66d0fa07a54688eba8fa506576a78a942ef243/server.go#L309-L314):

```
req.ParseForm()
if len(req.Form) > 0 {
    for k, v := range req.Form {
        ctx.Params[k] = v[0]
    }
}
```

In order to fix this, you'll need to add something that can parse the raw body of the response. You should just be able to use `ctx.Body` to access the raw body, since it implements `*http.Request` and doesn't redefine `Body` in the `Context` struct.

For example, this should work:

```
json := make(map[string]interface{})
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(ctx.Body)
if err != nil {
  // Handle Body read error
  return
}
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &json)
if err != nil {
  // Handle JSON parsing error
  return
}
// Use `json`
```